# How can I write a percent sign (%) at the beginning of a line in HAML?

Tags: escaping, haml

How can I start a line with a percent in HAML file?

This doesn't work:

```
%p
  = my_ruby_var
  %
```

=== UPDATE ===

Note: This answer is not accepted. I don't want any ruby to be computed:

```
%p
  = my_ruby_var
  = '%'
```

=== UPDATE 2 ===

For info: I discovered in the same doc reference that it is also possible to escape HTML as well:

*An **ampersand** followed by one or two equals characters evaluates Ruby code just like the equals without the ampersand, but **sanitizes any HTML-sensitive characters** in the result of the code.*

For example:

```
&= "I like cheese & crackers"
```

compiles to

```
I like cheese &amp; crackers
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
\%
```

maybe..

because it said in http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_
that \ is the escape character

Answer (score 2):

I just tested prefixing a % with a [\](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_) and it yielded the % symbol. Hope that helps